# Excel: Change cell to certain days

Tags: excel

I have a cell(ScheduleStart) that has the start date of a work schedule. In the A1 cell, I want to put the month name and four working days. (Monday-Thursday) Then in D1, I want the weekend work days. (Friday-Sunday)

Example:

```
ScheduleStart: Jul 12
A1: Jul 12,13,14,15,19,20,21,22
D1: Jul 16,17,18,23,24,25
```

How would I format A1 and D1 to be able to do this?

Comment: You're going to need to either write a function to produce this output, or else use some additional cells on the spreadsheet.

Either way, the 'formatting' would come from creating a string with the correct values in it.

Answer (score 0):

As Coldnorth said, you'll have to use formula or function to create what you want. A "format" cannot change the  of the cell.

You can use :

```
- in formula : TEXT
- in vba : FORMAT
```

and use date formatting :

```
- "mmm" short month label
- "dd" day number (with two digits)
```

To find working days, you can use the formula :

```
- WEEKDAY to find if you are monday / tuesday / ...
```

Btw, the formula NETWORKDAYS can help you having open days.

Please precise you question if you want more help,

Regards